# How to monitor oracle 11gr2 performace metrics using java or REST API

Tags: oracle11gr2

1. How to monitor oracle 11gr2 performance metrics and do we have any rest api to get the perfomance metrics.
2. How do we monitor performance metrics in 11gr2 and 12c?
3. Do we have REST API to query performance metric such as cpu utilization,memory usage etc.

Can some help me to understand how to query oracle DB performance metrics in java

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the REST service by starting the JVM running your service with debug switches. When that is done you can use something like the Visual VM profiler in Netbeans 8.2 or 9 to also monitor the Queries. You will need another tool to monitor the db itself.